# Express Router bypass

Tags: node.js, express, routes

In an express server, I am using user to display different things depending on permissions.

```
app.use("/user", ensureAdmin, ...myAdminFunc);
app.use("/user", ...myFunc);
```

Now, in my real code I have broken it into its own Express.Router object. And done `app.use(adminRoutes);`

All simple stuff currently. I found that the `next("route")` function doesn't work the way I expected. I have since read that I would STILL need to use the `ensureAdmin` middleware function on each route within the router.

I currently have below.

```
function ensureAdmin(req, res, next) {
    /*if not admin*/ next("route");
}
admin.get("/user", ensureAdmin, ...myAdminFunc);
admin.get("/other", ensureAdmin, ...myOtherAdminFunc);
```

I was hoping I could do a single middleware and bypass the whole router if needed. Something such as

```
function ensureAdmin(req, res, next) {
    /*if not admin*/ next("skip everything in this router");
}
admin = new Express.Router();
admin.use(ensureAdmin);
admin.get("/user", ...myAdminFunc);
admin.get("/other", ...myOtherAdminFunc);
```

but when I call `next("route")` within ensureAdmin it still goes on to the `admin.get("/user", ...myAdminFunc);` part.

I have read that this *IS* the expected behaviour for the `next("route")`

But wondering if there was a way that I have not been able to find yet to have it bypass everything within this admin Router collection? Maybe a `next("router")` or something?

I know the router itself doesn't count as a "route" but a route collection, which now makes sense why `next("route")` doesn't work.

- Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was implemented in 2017 under [THIS](https://github.com/expressjs/express/commit/9722202df964bfbfc0f579e4baeb5a4e1b43b344) commit, see [Line 121 of route.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L121)

Usage is as follows

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

function myAwesomeCheck() {
    // randomly pick a router to go with
    return (Math.random() > 0.5) 
}

const router1 = express.Router()

router1.use((req, res, next) => {
    // using next('router') will skip this entire router and pass to router2
    if(myAwesomeCheck() === true) next('router')
    // using next() will just pass to the middleware
    else next()
})

router1.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("I'm router 1, this means myAwesomeCheck was FALSE")
})

const router2 = express.Router()

router2.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("I'm router 2, this means myAwesomeCheck was TRUE")
})

app.use(router1, router2)
app.listen(3000)
```

This allows you to completely skip a router if conditions are not met, in the examples case, it will randomly skip router1 50% of the time

Comment: Yep. I use this in my code for quite a few years.

Comment: It seems sparsely documented, I was searching for ages today and this question kept popping up so I figured I'd leave an answer for the next poor soul!

Comment: Just to let you know, your comment about `next()` is wrong, `next()` passes you onto the next `middleware` of the route not to the next route.  I know it doesn't seem like that, but you can think of `.use()` as a way of prefixing all the routes that come after it with the middleware. EG `router1.get('/'. __middleware_from_use__, (req, res) => {....}) router1.get('/other', __middleware_from_use__, (req, res) => {...});`

Comment: You're completely correct! I had been typing `route` so much I got carried away! I've updated my answer :)